# How to filter values within a threshold in R

Tags: r, filter, dplyr

I have a data set that looks like this with the first 10 rows

```
country    freq

Albania     2           
Argentina   4           
Australia  26           
Austria    14           
Belgium    22           
Brazil     46           
Bulgaria   2            
Cambodia   2            
Canada     37           
Chile      19
```

I want to filter out counts(frequency) that are less than 30

i tried this code:

```
dd %>%
   group_by(freq) %>%
   filter(n()<30)
```

The output was same with the dataset. I did not get want i want

how do I resolve this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you done `dd <- dd %>%
   group_by(freq) %>%
   filter(n()<30)`

Comment: In `filter` you specify the observations to keep, not remove. And `n()` gives the number of rows, it sounds like you want to filter directly on the frequency value. No grouping is needed here. `dd %>% filter(freq >= 30)`

Comment: @Greg, thanks for the explanation.. i got it now

Answer (score 0):

Use simple indexing. Why are you grouping by?

```
dd <- dd[dd$freq >= 30, ]
```

Comment: @Greg, could you please, re-post your answer? you posted solution using  `group_by` to filter in a dataframe if the observation occur more than once in a column. I dont know why i cant find it here anymore